# WS2812B LEDs start flickering after some time

Tags: led, led-strip, ws2812

I've built a WordClock with a NodeMcu and some ws2812b LEDs some time ago and it worked really well for like half a year but now the LEDs are starting to flicker when the WordClock runs longer than some days.
[Video of the problem](https://photos.app.goo.gl/pAgSMkiKc4g1MWYr5)

I've got a 25w meanwell power supply, has this something to do with undervoltage? The strip is connected on both side to the PSU and I've measured stable 5V on the strip back when I installed them.
Any recommendations?

Comment: That looks more like a communication problem than a power supply problem.

Comment: that looks like a flash, not a flicker ... the LEDs brighten suddenly ... they do not waver in intensity like candle light .... maybe your code turns off all of the LEDs and then lights some of them, and the code loop gets paused when the leds are lit

Comment: It seems, that only the already lighted LEDs flash. Is that correct? (Is not easy to see behind the letters). Are you sure, that the voltage is really stable? If you have an oscilloscope, you could check for that. Please also show your code. Maybe it can give a hint about what is wrong. Just a wild guess: Have you checked, if the controlling Arduino maybe resets for some reason? Depending on the code that might cause such a problem

Comment: @chrisl the lighted LEDs are working normally but rather the LEDs right next to them have this flashing problem, I tweaked my code a little bit and reduced the update cycle of my FastLED library to only update when the minute actually changes, maybe this could prevent this from happening because before I used called my update lights function every 30ms.